# Как сделать приватными некоторые записи в wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

```
 <?php if(!is_user_logged_in()): ?>
        <p>You need to log in to view the status update!</p>
    <?php else : ?>
```

пробовала этот код использовать но видимо он работает не во всех темах одинакового хорошо.
можно использовать для каждой отдельной записи пароль, но это долго. как массово закрыть избранные записи (возможно используя теги или категории или id записей)? чтобы они имели такой вид https://i.stack.imgur.com/9c6We.png или что то типа ссылки на авторизацию, без разницы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте такой фильтр в function.php

```
function post_password_required_filter( $required, $post ) {
    $category = array(
        'Hidden Posts',
        'Old Posts',
    );
    $password = '12345';

    if ( in_category( $category, $post ) ) {
        require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-phpass.php';
        $hasher = new PasswordHash( 8, true );

        $hash = wp_unslash( $_COOKIE[ 'wp-postpass_' . COOKIEHASH ] );
        if ( 0 !== strpos( $hash, '$P$B' ) ) {
            $required = true;
        } else {
            if ( '' === $post->post_password ) {
                // Post does not have own password. Check category password.
                $required = ! $hasher->CheckPassword( $password, $hash );
            } else {
                // Post has own password. Check it.
                $required = ! $hasher->CheckPassword( $post->post_password, $hash );
            }
        }
    }

    return $required;
}

add_filter( 'post_password_required', 'post_password_required_filter', 10, 2 );
```

В данном примере осуществляется проверка по категориям. Вместо проверки на категории можно поставить любую другую.

Если у поста есть одна из категорий 'Hidden Posts' или 'Old Posts', то фильтр проверяет, какой пароль у текущего поста. Если он пустой, то проводится сравнение с заданным в фильтре паролем для категорий '12345'. Если у поста уже был установлен пароль при создании или редактировании, то производится сравнение с этим паролем.

При чем тут куки? А при том, что когда пользователь вводит пароль на сайте, WordPress устанавливает хешированные куки с введенным паролем. Вот эти куки мы и проверяем в фильтре.

Функция `get_the_content()`, через которую идёт вывод постов, проверяет возможность отображения поста через

```
if ( post_password_required() ) { ... }
```

А `post_password_required()`, в свою очередь, вызывает фильтр `post_password_required`.

Код проверен, работает на моем тестовом сайте. Все записи категории Uncategorized http://test.kagg.eu/category/uncategorized/ закрыты паролем 12345, кроме самого верхнего поста в этой категории, для которого в админке установлен свой пароль - 777.

Comment: то есть вместо 'Hidden Posts', 'Old Posts', я пишу название своих категорий. ладно работает. записи защищены паролем. но как узнать сам пароль? которым они защищены

Comment: Дополнил ответ насчет проверки паролей

Comment: вот теперь здорово :)